# Node.js + websocket - Low-bandwidth game entity ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, multiplayer, uid

I have been working on a game for the past few days and I am currently working on **optimizing the websocket frame data**. I've changed data type from simple JSON to an **arraybuffer**, and that part is working fine. Entity data such as **position and rotation is sent and received with no problem**.

The **entity `ID`** is the problem. Currently the **client is keeping track of every entity by its `ID`** to store last position for the smooth movement, and **so it will continue to be.**

Every entity on the server currently has an `UUID` (ex `f2e9f5e2-a810-416e-a1ce-a300a0b7a088`). That is **16 bytes**. Im not sending that!

And now to my question. How to they do it in big games? Is there any way of getting around this, or a way to generate a unique 2 byte or some other low-bandwith `UID`?

**UPDATE**

I need more than 256 `ID`s, which means that 1 byte is obviously not going to work. 2 bytes gives me 65535 `ID`s which probably is enough. I also know that iterating through a loop until you find the next free ID is an option, but maybe that is too "costly".

Comment: UUIDs are only 16 bytes, not 36. And, sure, you can generate 1 byte IDS as long as you don't need more than 256 of them.

Comment: You can use protocol buffers, and use integer/longs instead of strings, of course depending on how many IDs you need.

Comment: I need more than 256 IDs, which obviously excludes 1 byte. 2 bytes may it, but then I would have to loop through and see which is the next free id?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen And how to I convert the UUID string stored on the server to the binary 16 bytes?

Comment: What library are you using? [`node-uuid`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid/) lets you generate UUIDs directly into a buffer. [`uuid-parse`](https://github.com/zefferus/uuid-parse/) lets you convert between string and buffer.